# Why is the conditional marker "бы" omitted from the construction "Я должен был предвидеть, что ..."?

Tags: грамматика

> Я **должен был предвидеть**, что ...

Given the counterfactual conditional aspect of this phrasing, I'd expected to see the conditional marker "бы". I wonder why you can drop "бы" in this particular instance, even though we're clearly talking about something that didn't happen in the past.

I assume the literal translation is something like: "I **had to be foreseeing / expecting** that ...". Incidentally, you'd use the conditional tense "j'aurais dû ..." in French to describe the same idea.

Is there another phrasing like this that conveys a conditional meaning without using  "бы"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are sentences when the **conditional** clause is marked with **бы**, and the main clause is used in the **indicative** because we have modal verbs **мочь и должен** instead. The rule is about **counterfactual** (unrealized ) events. That's just your sentence, though it has only main clause.

> Если бы в мои планы входило украсть что-нибудь, я мог вынести даже прилавок. [А. Геласимов. Год обмана (2003)]
>
> Конечно, бабушка и без нее бы обошлась, но если бы она не взялась помогать, в семье могла произойти ссора. [«Мурзилка» (2002)]
>
> Если бы они померли сами, то должны были где-нибудь валяться. [А. Геласимов. Степные боги (2008)]

There's another possibility to omit бы, when it is used for **politeness or to express wish**. We can have indicative mood after if, and **бы** in the main clause.
The situation refers to **present or future** and can be realized.

> Но если нам по пути, я проводил бы вас… с вашего позволения…[Ю. Буйда. Город палачей (2003)] (politeness )
>
> Но, если вы не возражаете, я бы спросил вас кое о чем предварительно. [В. Белоусова. По субботам не стреляю (2000)] (politeness )
>
> – Людмила Викторовна, раз уж зашла речь, я бы хотел попросить ненадолго ваши камни, те, с которыми Аркадий Викторович экспериментировал. [Е. Парнов. Третий глаз Шивы (1985)] (politeness )
>
> Если ее выгнали из квартиры, оставила бы мне весточку. [В. Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным (1998)] (wish)
>
> «А вы если не смогли со всем разобраться, то подавали бы давно рапорт, уходили б в отставку!» [О. Павлов. Казенная сказка (1993)] (wish)

Answer (score 3):

The following quotation may explain this phenomenon, although in the source article it doesn't directly relate to sentences of the type in question

> Возможность опущения частицы сослагательного наклонения при глаголе
>   **мочь** и прилагательном **должен** связана с тем, что эти модальные слова
>   частично синонимичны сослагательному наклонению: они участвуют в
>   обозначении ситуации, которая является не вполне реализованной ([Bybee
>   1995]; [Добрушина 2014]). Это свойство модальных предикатов
>   проявляется и в других конструкциях, например в относительных
>   предложениях.

source [http://rusgram.ru/Сослагательное_наклонение#423](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#423)

However in a classic conditional sentence with conjunction **если бы/будь** the particle **бы** would absolutely have to be appended

> **Если бы** я **был**/**Будь** я ясновидящим, я **должен был бы** предвидеть, что нам отключат воду.

But like other participants i tend to think that your example isn't a part of a conditional sentence.

Just as in English one can say

> I `would have to` foresee, that...

OR

> I `would have had` to foresee, that...

OR

> I `had to` foresee, that...

which all express different moods

Comment: I'd think this 1. applies to present tense only (ситуация, которая является не вполне реализованной) - purely a personal feeling, I'd use it anyway, and 2. states that it's *possible* to omit the particle, not that it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see conditional aspect here. It's past tense. Compare to "Я должен был пойти в кино (но остался дома)".  Anyway, you can say it with "бы" too:

> Я должен был бы предвидеть, что...

Comment: From an English/French speaker's perspective, a conditional aspect is perceived here: "I should have known that  ... {conditional}" vs "I knew that ... {fact}". :)

Comment: Hi. By the way, it is not correct to say "Я должен **предвидел**, что ...", correct? Does the "быть" verb always need to come in between like an auxiliary verb?

Comment: @Alone-zee of course, because должен is technically an adjective (a short form of должный), and grammatically is a predicative adjective

Answer (score 1):

```
Я должен был предвидеть, что …

…we're clearly talking about something that didn't happen in the past.
```

If you are absolutely sure (from a larger context) that you are talking about a counterfactual event, then your Russian phrase is wrong. What is your source? If not a good book, then it's probably a case of hypercorrection (similar to an English "he invited my husband and I to lunch"), because there is indeed a "low literacy" marker of people using more "бы" than the grammar calls for, [here's](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#33) a description of such overuse.

Have a read if that huge article anyway, maybe 4.1 is your case - it still does require the particle.

To summarise the article, though:

```
Сослагательное наклонение обозначает ситуации, не существующие в реальном мире.
Сослагательное наклонение выражается аналитически с помощью частицы бы (б).
```

Full stop.

If you assume that "Я должен был предвидеть, что…" by itself indicates a counterfactual aspect, then perhaps it's your view on life that needs adjustment. Or at least your Russian grammar! ;)

Counterfactuality here doesn't follow from "Я должен был". In Russian the phrase is simply a factual statement about the past - he had to have foreseen (he didn't foresee, but still *had* to)